# How do I create a system partition on an empty machine

Tags: windows, partitioning, setup

I am trying to install windows on a PC. However, the windows install fails because it can't install find or create the system partition.

I can't run diskpart.exe because windows is not installed.

How do I create a system partition so that I install windows?

Comment: Which version of Windows is this? Every version since NT 4.0 or so has been able to do it during the install.

Comment: I am trying to install Windows 8. Apparently, the install does not know how to create a system partition

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because Windows doesn't have drivers for your harddisk controller.

In there will be a way to install drivers during installation, download disk related drivers from the website of the vendor of your PC, the Windows 7 drivers should work fine.  Then install when you install windows.